# Where is $k(z)=PV(z-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}PV(z+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ Continuous and Differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

> Consider the function ($PV$ denotes the *principal value*) $$PV(z-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}PV(z+1)^{\frac{1}{2}},  \ \ \forall z\in\mathbb{C}.$$
>   Find where $k$ is continuous and differentiable, giving reasons.

We first recall that $f(w)=w^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not continuous when $w<0$. Using this, we can conclude that $PV(z-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not continuous when $z<1$ and  $PV(z+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not continuous when $z<-1$. Hence, $k(z)$ is not continuous when $z<1$.

Is this sufficient to determine that $k(z)$ is not differentiable on the interval $(-\infty, 1)$, as $k(z)$ is not continuous for $z<1$ and not differentiable at $z=1$ (by inspection)?

Comment: What are $P$ and $V$? Constants?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. $PV$ denotes the principal value of the square root.

Comment: The overlap of branch cuts may cancel the discontinuous.

Comment: @Kemono Chen Are you able to explain this a bit further

Comment: Consider $f(z)=\ln z-\ln(z-1)$, its branch cut is a straight line from $0$ to $1$, not from $-\infty$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Carefully rewrite $f(z)=\text{PV}(z-1)^{1/2}(z+1)^{1/2}$ as $\exp\left(\frac{\ln(z-1)+\ln(z+1)}2\right)$.
Consider $g(z)=\frac{\ln(z-1)+\ln(z+1)}2$, $$\lim_{z\to x,\Re z>0}g(z)=g(x),x<1$$
$$\lim_{z\to x,\Re z<0}g(z)=g(x)-\pi i,-1<x<1$$
$$\lim_{z\to x,\Re z<0}g(z)=g(x)-2\pi i,x<-1$$
Hence, $$\lim_{z\to x,\Re z>0}f(z)=f(x),x<1$$
$$\lim_{z\to x,\Re z<0}f(z)=-f(x),-1<x<1$$
$$\lim_{z\to x,\Re z<0}f(z)=f(x),x<-1$$
Therefore, $f(z)$ is discontinuous at $-1<x<1$.
One can prove $$\lim_{z\to1}f(z)=\lim_{z\to-1}f(z)=0,$$ hence it is continuous at $z=1$ and $-1$, but not continuous at neighborhood of $z=1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I just ask though, why is my argument invalid? That is, given $PV(z-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not continuous for $z<1$ and $PV(z+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not continuous for $z<-1$, why isn't $k(z)$ discontinuous for $z<1$?

Comment: @JulianAngussmith As I said in comment, overlapping may make branch cut disappear. Consider $f(z)=\sqrt z$, $g(z)=1-\sqrt z$. Both $f(z)$ and $g(x)$ have a branch cut. Why is $f(z)+g(z)$ entire? Because if we add/multiply two (or more) branch cuts together, it may disappear.

Comment: Why does the branch cut disappear for $k(z)$?

Comment: @JulianAngussmith Because you add/multiply them together.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works. Multiplying them together, why is the interval $(-\infty,-1)$ no longer discontinuous. This is what I don't understand.

Comment: @JulianAngussmith see my $g(z)$, on upside of $z<-1$, it is $g(z)$, on downside, it is $g(z)-2\pi i$. Since $\exp$ has a period $2\pi i$, they perfectly cancel out.